# Drupal views: Civicrm drupal_id entity missing after update?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity

Inside Drupal views, I use some contextual filters and relationships which, I think, are provided by CiviCRM Entities.

Before Civi 5.15, some seemed to be provided by CiviCRM itself (?). Under 'relationships, for example, there was 'CiviCRM Contacts: Drupal ID' which did **not** say 'provided by CiviCRM Entities'.

[image]

After an update to 5.15, that relationship, and a whole bunch of others, are gone. Under relationships, the only one left is 'CiviCRM Contact: Entity translation: translations Translation information.'

Also under 'contextual filters', a lot of civicrm filters, but not all, are gone.

What am I missing ? Have they moved somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem has disappeared.

Ehm, I cleared caches. Fairly sure I cleared caches the first time, but I did it again, now using the UI, and all looks normal now.

Comment: Phew! Glad to hear that. Yeah - rule of thumb with civicrm_entity is to always clear caches twice. I think that may even be documented somewhere.